How to put a frame or box like a square - the example given does NOT work
I got this straight from Overleaf but I get an error.
This is my picture:
\fbox{%
\begin{picture}(3,3)
\put(0,0){{\color{blue}\circle*{0.25}}\hbox{\kern3pt \texttt{(0,0)}}}
\put(3,3){{\color{red}\circle*{0.25}}\hbox{\kern3pt \texttt{(3,3)}}}
\end{picture}}

and it states the \fbox command draws a border around the bounding box of the graphic, showing the space (area) reserved by LaTeX.
But when I run it get this error message:

File ended while scanning use of \fbox.

What is wrong?

Can you please add the missing lines, so it will compile? Thank you

You have an \fbox{ with no matching } but that does not appear to be from the code you show, which generates no error in a simple test document
